# Cannot resolve method checkSelfPermission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions

I'm trying to make my app ready for Android 6 and now I'm stuck to the point where you need to request and check permissions.

I tried the following from the docs:

`int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);`

The problem is that Android Studio says `Cannot resolve method 'checkSelfPermission'`.

I already included the appcompat and support lib. `ContextCompat` is known to AS but the method itself isn't known. I don't know what am I doing wrong - in another project I can write this method and it gets recognized.

TargetAPI is 23.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Is that method written inside activity? or fragment? or a utility class?

Comment: It is inside the onCreate of an Activity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh my godness - what a stupid mistake.

AS imported the supportlib as a jar and this jar was from like 2014. I just replaced the jarimport with the real dependency and know it is working.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: For someone that is literally in your exact same situation (where everyone else's answers would not apply to my case), but hasn't really understood how you solved it, could you please elaborate? What exactly did you replace, with what? Thank you in advance!

Comment: same issue, imported from eclipse and it dragged old support jar with it. So, check your app libs folder cause AS will import from there, make sure there is no old jars there (i just deleted them),  and add dependency in your app build gradle  e.g. implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.+'

Answer (score 26):

Here is how you need to call in various scenarios,

In case of activity:

```
 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyActivity.this,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

In case of fragment:

```
 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

In case of any utility class use context:

```
 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

Comment below for further information

Comment: If it is in onCreate() you can use this:   ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);

Comment: AS tells me it does not know the function `checkSelfPermission` that's the problem.
If it helps: The project is imported from Eclipse.
The other one I mentioned above, where I can do the permissioncheck is an originally AS project

Comment: Okay can you post your build.gradle.

Comment: See my answer below - fixed it :o Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It requires API 23.

Comment: what should we do to checkSelfPermission inside an adapter?

Comment: @ShinoyShaji  I think you might wanna perform some action on clicking an adapter row, If that is the case i recommend you to have a callback from adapter onto activity, Or else you can pass activity in the adapter constructor and perform permission check.

Answer (score 5):

For `Fragment` use `getActivity().checkSelfPermission`

For `Activity` use `this..checkSelfPermission` or simply `checkSelfPermission`

Answer (score 1):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

I simply used this on top of my page and it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

As silly as it maybe, it could be in the wrong place. I had the same problem. The bolded part is where I had originally put the code. The italic part is where it should have gone

```
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("-----------", location.toString());
    }
    **if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {'some code'}**
    }; 'End of LocationListener method
    *if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 'some code'}*
```

Comment: Hmm Editing did not do as it said. The 'bolded' section is actually enclosed by " ** ", the 'italic' section is enclosed by " * "

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case I added a library that was using an old appcompat version, then the compiler could not find the right appcompat.

To fix the problem I added the option {transitive = false} while importing the culprit library, and this fixed the problem.

Now I have:

`api ('org.library.using.old.appcompat:1.0.1') {transitive = false}`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use `checkSelfPermission()` in a `Fragment` with Kotlin and wondering how to get around `Context` being null?

Have a look at the sample below, and remember, before the `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity`, the `Context` will be null.

```
private fun fineLocationPermissionApproved(): Boolean {

    val context = context ?: return false

    return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkSelfPermission(
        context,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )
}
```